# cudaErrorIllegalAdress on cudaMemcpy

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust

I am new to cuda and trying to write a little code which should generate random points on a sphere. Here is the code.

```
    __global__ 
    void setup_kernel(curandStateMRG32k3a *state) 
    { 
      int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
      curand_init(0, id, 0, &state[id]); 
    }

    __global__
    void computeRandomVectors(float* x, float* y, float* z, unsigned int numberOfElements,curandStateMRG32k3a *state)
    {
      float a,b;
      unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
      curandStateMRG32k3a localState = state[i];
      if(i < numberOfElements)
        {
          a = curand_uniform(&localState);
          b = curand_uniform(&localState);
          while(a * a + b * b > 1.0f)
        {
          a = curand_uniform(&localState) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
          b = curand_uniform(&localState) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
        }
          x[i] = 2.0f * a * sqrtf(1.0f - a * a - b * b);
          y[i] = 2.0f * b * sqrtf(1.0f - a * a - b * b);
          z[i] = 1.0f - 2.0f * (a * a + b * b);
        }
     }

    void generatePointsOnASphere(thrust::host_vector<float>& h_x,        thrust::host_vector<float>& h_y, thrust::host_vector<float>& h_z)
    {
      if(h_x.size() != h_y.size() && h_x.size() != h_z.size())
        {
          std::cout << "The three component vectors have unmatching  size()" << std::endl;
          return;
        }

      size_t size = h_x.size() * sizeof(float);

      float* h_p_x = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
      float* h_p_y = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
      float* h_p_z = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
      if(h_p_x==NULL || h_p_y==NULL || h_p_z==NULL)
        {
          std::cout << "Host memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
           return;
         }

      float* d_p_x;
      float* d_p_y;
      float* d_p_z;

    if(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_x,size) != cudaSuccess || 
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_y,size) != cudaSuccess ||
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_z,size) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Device memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    curandStateMRG32k3a *devStates;
    if(cudaMalloc((void **)&devStates, h_x.size() * sizeof(curandStateMRG32k3a)) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Random generator states memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

  int threads = 256;
  dim3 grid = size / threads;
  setup_kernel<<<grid,threads>>>(devStates);

  if(cudaMemcpy(d_p_x,h_p_x,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess ||
     cudaMemcpy(d_p_y,h_p_y,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess ||
     cudaMemcpy(d_p_z,h_p_z,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout <<  "Host to Device memory copy failure" << std::endl;
    }

  computeRandomVectors<<< grid, threads >>>(d_p_x,d_p_y,d_p_z,size / sizeof(float), devStates);

  if(cudaMemcpy(h_p_x,d_p_x,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess ||
     cudaMemcpy(h_p_y,d_p_y,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess ||
     cudaMemcpy(h_p_z,d_p_z,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;      
      std::cout <<  "Device to Host memory copy failure" << std::endl;
    }
  for(size_t i = 0; i < h_x.size(); ++i)
    {
      h_x[i] = h_p_x[i];
      h_y[i] = h_p_y[i];
      h_z[i] = h_p_z[i];
    }

  free (h_p_x);
  free (h_p_y);
  free (h_p_z);
  cudaFree (devStates);
  cudaFree (d_p_x);
  cudaFree (d_p_y);
  cudaFree (d_p_z);
  cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

This code works if the number of elements in the vectors is less than 4000 (I tried 1K,2K,3K and 4K). Than it gives me cuda Error Illegal Address in the first cudaMemcpy. I don't think I run out of memory, I am working with gtx 980 (4GB of global memory). Any idea how to fix this?

---

**EDIT**: The code after the suggested modifications is the following:

```
__global__ 
void setup_kernel(curandStateMRG32k3a *state, unsigned int numberOfElements) 
{ 
  int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if(id < numberOfElements) curand_init(0, id, 0, &state[id]); 
}

__global__
void computeRandomVectors(float* x, float* y, float* z, unsigned int numberOfElements,curandStateMRG32k3a *state)
{
  float a,b;
  unsigned int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  curandStateMRG32k3a localState = state[i];
  if(i < numberOfElements)
    {
      a = curand_uniform(&localState);
      b = curand_uniform(&localState);
      while(a * a + b * b > 1.0f)
     {
       a = curand_uniform(&localState) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
       b = curand_uniform(&localState) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
     }
      x[i] = 2.0f * a * sqrtf(1.0f - a * a - b * b);
      y[i] = 2.0f * b * sqrtf(1.0f - a * a - b * b);
      z[i] = 1.0f - 2.0f * (a * a + b * b);
     }
 }

 void generatePointsOnASphere(thrust::host_vector<float>& h_x, thrust::host_vector<float>& h_y, thrust::host_vector<float>& h_z)
 {
  if(h_x.size() != h_y.size() && h_x.size() != h_z.size())
    {
      std::cout << "The three component vectors have unmatching size()" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

   size_t size = h_x.size() * sizeof(float);

   float* h_p_x = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
   float* h_p_y = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
   float* h_p_z = (float*) calloc(h_x.size(),sizeof(float));
   if(h_p_x==NULL || h_p_y==NULL || h_p_z==NULL)
    {
      std::cout << "Host memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

   float* d_p_x;
   float* d_p_y;
   float* d_p_z;

   if(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_x,size) != cudaSuccess || 
 cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_y,size) != cudaSuccess ||
 cudaMalloc((void **)&d_p_z,size) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Device memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
      return;
     }
  curandStateMRG32k3a *devStates;
  if(cudaMalloc((void **)&devStates, h_x.size() * sizeof(curandStateMRG32k3a)) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Random generator states memory allocation failure" << std::endl;
      return;
    }

  if(cudaMemcpy(d_p_x,h_p_x,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess ||
 cudaMemcpy(d_p_y,h_p_y,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess ||
 cudaMemcpy(d_p_z,h_p_z,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;
      std::cout <<  "Host to Device memory copy failure" << std::endl;
     }

  int threads = 512;
  dim3 grid = (h_x.size() + threads - 1) / threads;
  setup_kernel<<<grid,threads>>>(devStates, size / sizeof(float));
  computeRandomVectors<<< grid, threads >>>(d_p_x,d_p_y,d_p_z,size / sizeof(float), devStates);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  if(cudaMemcpy(h_p_x,d_p_x,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess ||
 cudaMemcpy(h_p_y,d_p_y,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess ||
 cudaMemcpy(h_p_z,d_p_z,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess)
    {
      std::string errorString(cudaGetErrorName(cudaGetLastError()));
      std::cout << errorString << std::endl;      
      std::cout <<  "Device to Host memory copy failure" << std::endl;
    }
  for(size_t i = 0; i < h_x.size(); ++i)
    {
      h_x[i] = h_p_x[i];
      h_y[i] = h_p_y[i];
      h_z[i] = h_p_z[i];
    }

  free (h_p_x);
  free (h_p_y);
  free (h_p_z);
  cudaFree (devStates);
  cudaFree (d_p_x);
  cudaFree (d_p_y);
  cudaFree (d_p_z);
  cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

I feel sorry for keeping posting here but I think by understanding what are my mistakes now I think I might get a better understanding of cuda. 
So, now I am getting errorIllegalAdress on cudaMemcpy device->host when h_x.size() is 20k. I still do not understand how the code works for small numbers but not for big ones.

Comment: You haven't provided a complete code.  When I build a complete code around what you have now shown with your EDIT, I get no errors of any kind.  My completely worked example is [here](http://pastebin.com/uGy0cTcb).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: apparently #include <curand.h> made the difference!!! Very stupid mistake of mine, but comparison to your code showed it. For the range of values I need it is ok finally but for curiosity I tried to reach higher values and at 100k it gives me Device to host memory copy failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
  size_t size = h_x.size() * sizeof(float);

  ...
  int threads = 256;
  dim3 grid = size / threads;
```

Your `size` variable is scaled by the number of *bytes*.  So that is not the correct variable to use for the grid size.  You should compute the grid size like this:

```
  dim3 grid = h_x.size() / threads;
```

or similar.  Also note that this construct won't properly initialize all curand state unless the vector length (`h_x.size()`) is evenly divisible by `threads` i.e. 256.  The method to address this would be to include a thread check in your `setup_kernel` similar to the one in your other kernel:

```
__global__ 
void setup_kernel(curandStateMRG32k3a *state, int size) 
{ 
  int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if (id < size)
    curand_init(0, id, 0, &state[id]); 
}
```

and launch enough threads to cover the vector size:

```
  dim3 grid = (h_x.size()+threads-1) / threads;
```

Comment: I did the modification you suggested and it works much better now. However, if I go up to 20k points the problems is there again. I still do not understand how the mistakes I did in the kernel launches can influence the host to device memcpy which happens before.

Comment: The host to device memcpy is **after** the `setup_kernel` launch.  Failures in that kernel will show up asynchronously in those cudaMemcpy operations which are after the `setup_kernel` launch.

Comment: If you have errors showing up in the very first host to device memcpy, it's also possible that those errors are originating from some other code before all this (ie. before you call generatePointsOnASphere()).  Since you haven't shown a complete code, I wouldn't be able to discover those errors.  Try running the complete code I have in the pastebin link.